# An infinite minimal strongly KC-space possesses a non-trivial

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

The notion of strongly KC-spaces mean  spaces
in which every countably compact subset is closed.

a space $(X,‎\tau‎ )$ is said to
be minimal strongly KC if $(X,‎\tau‎ )$ is  strongly KC but no topology
on X which is strictly smaller  than $\tau‎ $ is strongly KC.

**An infinite minimal strongly KC-space possesses a non-trivial
convergent sequence**.

**P r o o f** . Suppose $X$ is such a space. we know that, X is countably
compact. Let $ p ∈ X$ be non-isolated. Then$ X-\{p\}$ is not closed, hence not countably
compact, since $ X$ is strongly $KC$. So there is a countably infinite subset $A ⊂ X - \{p\}$
which has no accumulation points in $X - \{p\}$ and therefore, for every $x ∈ A$, there
is an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$ such that $ U_{x} ∩ A = \{x\}$. $p$ is the
unique accumulation point of $A$ in $X$ and  $A ∪ \{p\}$ is closed in $X$. Thus $A ∪ \{p\}$
is countably compact and hence compact in $X$. Let $A = \{x_{n} : n ∈ \omega \}$. for any open neighborhood $V$ of $p$, the collection $\{U_{x_{n}} : n ∈ \omega  \}∪ \{V \}$ is an open
cover of$ A∪\{p\}$ and hence it has a finite subcover, say, $ ‎U‎_{x‎_{n‎_{‎1‎}‎}‎}‎‎‎ ∪ ‎U‎_{x‎_{n‎_{‎2‎}‎}‎}‎‎‎ ∪. . . ∪‎U‎_{x‎_{n‎_{k}‎}‎}‎‎‎ ∪ V $.
Since $‎U‎_{x‎_{n‎_{i}‎}‎}‎‎‎ ∩ A = \{x_{n_{i}} \}$ for $i = 1, 2, . . . , k$, it follows that $x_{n}  ∈ V $ whenever $n > n_{k}$
and this implies $x_{n} → p (n → ∞)$

> (1): why does **exist**   a point like  $p$ such that $ p ∈ X$ is **non-isolated**? and $ X-\{p\}$ is not closed?
>
> (2) Is $p$ **unique** accumulation point of $A$ in $X$ due to $A ∪ \{p\}$ is closed in $X$?if not why $p$  is **unique** accumulation point of $A$ in $X$?
>
> (3) why $x_{n}  ∈ V $ whenever $n > n_{k}$?

.

Answer (score 1):

1. If every point of $X$ were isolated, then $X$ would be discrete, and an infinite discrete space is not countably compact. Thus, $X$ must have a non-isolated point $p$. Finally, the statement that $p$ is not isolated is by definition just the statement that $\{p\}$ is not open and hence that $X\setminus\{p\}$ is not closed.
2. $A$ has no accumulation point in $X\setminus\{p\}$, but $X$ is countably compact, so $A$ must have an accumulation point in $X$. The only point of $X$ that is not in $X\setminus\{p\}$ is $p$, so $p$ is the unique accumulation point of $A$.
3. The author meant to specify that $n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_k$. If $n>n_k$, then $n\notin\{n_1,\ldots,n_k\}$, so $x_n\in A\setminus(U_{n_1}\cup U_{n_2}\cup\ldots\cup U_{n_k})\subseteq V$, since $\{U_{n_1},U_{n_2},\ldots,U_{n_k}\}\cup\{V\}$ covers $A$. Thus, $x_n\in V$ for all $n>n_k$.